# SwiftUI Picker Focus on selected item in view

Tags: ios, swift, focus, picker

I'm trying to have the selected item in the Picker display at the top of the view. I have added. standard picker:

```
Section(){
    Picker(selection: $selectedYear, label: Text("")) {
        ForEach(2000...2050, id: \.self) {
            Text(String($0))
        }
    }
}
```

2020 is currently selected, however when the view appears it displays from 2000 at the top, 2020 outside of the screen with a check next to it.

[image: View from Picker]

Answer (score 1):

Pickers in SwiftUI need a tag to work.

```swift
Section(){
    Picker(selection: $selectedYear, label: Text("")) {
        ForEach(2000...2050, id: \.self) {
            Text(String($0)).tag($0) // <= add this to work
        }
    }
}
```